# AnimateWindow Winforms causing hyperlinks to disapear

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using AnimateWindow from C++ to show a toast notification in the bottom right of my monitor. This all works fine in terms of animation so there's not a functionality issue.

My Toasts are Forms styled to look "nice" using Form.Load, Form.Close to set the window position and show it via the animation.

My issue is as the form is animating I lose hyperlinks and images. These appear again when the form is stationary.

Has anyone come across a similar issue as this? At first, I assumed it was a parenting issue which I attempted to solve by setting the parent of the Hyperlink and Icons to *this* which didn't solve the issue and I'm stumped from here on.

Comment: If you're using c++ why have you posted this to the c# group

Comment: I'm using the AnimateWindow method from C++ to animate a .NET Form.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with parenting as suspected. I solved this by setting the parent of the icon on top of the control below to the below control.

```
foregroundImage.parent = backgroundImage;
```

Comment: This is not useful Q+A in its current form.  The snippet is particularly unhelpful.  If you don't want to take the time to work on it, at least with a repro snippet in the question, then consider simply deleting it.

Comment: What else would you want from an answer (genuinely curious)? This was literally the line that fixed the issue, it describes that the foreground parent is to be set to the background image, but if you insist that this isn't helpful I'll remove the post and hope nobody else comes into a similar issue because I found no information about this anywhere else and this could save someone an hour or two of looking.